# Java: Having trouble finding the minimum value of a Queue?

Tags: java, arraylist, queue

I'm using arraylist to implement a queue. Everything is going good except when I try to find the minimum value of the queue it does not work properly and the dequeue and peek functions for some reason do not work as expected. I tried going through line by line but I don't understand what is going wrong in the min() function:

```
public class queuePractice {

static ArrayList<Integer>nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
static int top = -1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    enqueue(5);
    enqueue(2);
    enqueue(6);
    enqueue(3);
    enqueue(12);
    enqueue(1);
    enqueue(20);

    System.out.println("The min is: "  + min());
}

public static int peek() {
    return nums.get(0);
}

public static void enqueue(int x) {
    nums.add(++top, x);
}

public static int dequeue() {
    top--;
    return nums.remove(0);
}

public static void display() {
    for(int x = 0; x <=top; x++) {
        System.out.print(nums.get(x) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static boolean isEmpty() {
    return top==-1;
}

public static int min() {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    while(min > peek()) {
        min = peek();
        dequeue();

    }
    return min;
}
}
```

The peek function keeps returning 2 over and over, even if I change the while loop to a for loop. For some reason it is not updating its value whenever I dequeue it? But going through line by line I can't understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier method would be

```
    List<Integer>nums = Arrays.asList(5,2,35,6);  // or use your enqueue

    Iterator<Integer> it = nums.iterator();

    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Integer i = it.next();
        min = Math.min(i, min);
    }
    System.out.println(min);
```

Of course any type of looping around the List would work

Comment: Ah I see now. The min > peek statement caused it to run around in circles.

Comment: or semi-circles anyway

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean your code is printing 2 all the time? That's because your min() method always terminate on 2

First iteration your int min value will be 5

Second iteration your int min value will be 2

Third iteration your loop will exit since 2 is not bigger than 6

Then your method will return 2

hope it helps

Comment: I see the logic but I don't understand why it's terminating when I'm losing a while loop and not a for loop? There shouldn't be any constraints here right? Dequeue should not be affecting anything since it's simply the arraylist using its own function to remove an index properly. So the problem lies in the peek() function? But that is doing a similar thing, just returning the value of the index of 0.

Comment: You need to loop through all elements, but your loop is only looping whilst `min > peek()`